# Convert an object to an array of a specific format

Tags: javascript

I get an array of objects, something like this

```
[{
  "name": "AAAA",
  "desig": "XXXX"
}, {
  "name": "BBBB",
  "desig": "YYYY"
}]
```

Is there a way to convert the above array into the below format

```
[
  [
    { "value": "AAAA"}, 
    {"value": "XXXX"}
  ],
  [
    { "value": "BBBB"}, 
    {"value": "YYYY"}
  ]
]
```

So for i have tried something like

```js
const Data = [{
  "name": "AAAA",
  "desig": "XXXX"
}, {
  "name": "BBBB",
  "desig": "YYYY"
}];

const array= Data.map(
  Data => ({"value": Data.name, "value": Data.desig})
);

console.log(array);
```

This only gives output like
[{"value": "XXXX"}, {"value": "YYYY"}].

I am really new to this javascript map(). Could someone pls helpme

Comment: Yes there's a way. What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Step 1: Convert `{
"name": "AAAA",
"desig": "XXXX",
}` to `[{ "value": "AAAA"}, {"value": "XXXX"}]`. Step 2: Use `Array.prototype.map` to convert every element.

Comment: Just FYI, what you have is an array of objects, which has nothing to do with JSON. This may have affected your attempts to research the problem

Comment: I have updated my question with what i have tried so far.. could someone pls help me understand how this map works

Comment: _"I am really new to this javascript map()."_ The problem is not in using `map`. It looks like you skipped step 1. In step 1, the conversion should result in an array containing two objects. Your conversion produces an object with two same keys. Again, try to convert `{ "name": "AAAA", "desig": "XXXX", }` to `[{ "value": "AAAA"}, {"value": "XXXX"}]`. Then, wrap it in `map`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do this,
const array = Data.map(d=> [d])
Basically map function is used for titration of array and return a new array so as per your requirement you just need to wrap your initial array child value into sub array , so you just need to get the value and wrap it inside [].

Comment: No, that doesn't produce the expected result.